# When is the object creation invoked in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, new-operator, authlogic

```
    class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Am new to RoR, So long i have been working on tradition c/c++ so i have some basic doubts about object creation and stuff,
In UserSessionsController there is two methods namely "new" and "create". In the "new" method an object for UserSession is created without any parameters and in "create" method again object is created with some parameter.

Initially i thought that the "new" method is redundant and removed it. But i recieved the following error

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

The code works fine if i include the "new" method. I couldn't see this method being called anywhere in the entire code. Am referring to following sample project

[railscasts/160-authlogic](https://github.com/railscasts/160-authlogic/tree/master/blog)

Kindly let me know how this object creation is happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new` and `create` are part of **[CRUD](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running)**.

`new` action is used to render the `new` view for the `UserSessionsController`. In `new` action you simply create an **instance** of `UserSession` model class with `@user_session = UserSession.new`. After this, `new.html.***`(*** is template handler like erb, haml, etc) is rendered where you will enter details of `UserSession` object that you would like to be created. Upon submission of this form `create` action would be invoked.

In `create` action you collect the parameters passed from the `new` view with `@user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])` and when you say `@user_session.save` it actually **creates a record in database table `user_sessions`**

**UPDATE**

The `new` action is invoked when you click on the **[Login Link](https://github.com/railscasts/160-authlogic/blob/68723e9aa4d0ae28d9c0d07cb90dbceec99d89d9/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb#L17)**. Why is it invoked? Because you have defined the `login_path` in **[routes.rb](https://github.com/railscasts/160-authlogic/blob/master/blog/config/routes.rb#L2)**

Since you are a beginner I would highly recommend you to:

1. Read the **[Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)** which will help you to understand the fundamentals of a Rails Application development.
2. Then, I also recommend you to complete **[Learn Rails by Example By
   Michael Hartl](http://www.railstutorial.org/book)**.
3. And finally, watch the **[Ruby on Rails Railscasts By Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/)**.

Although, you can search on Google and you will find many great resources for the Rails beginners but the above 3 are THE de facto ones.

Comment: Thank you. So now i got the purpose of those two methods. Could you explain me when and how the "new" action is invoked?

Comment: Read the UPDATE section in my answer and also follow the links that point to relevant code.

Comment: @VinodhKumar Also added more resources for your learning. Good Luck. Welcome to Rails World! :)

Comment: Hope my answer guides you in the right direction. Glad to help :)

Comment: Yeah Thanks :) And you guys have to answer lot of my questions on rails in the forth coming days ;) Be prepared ;)

Comment: @VinodhKumar Is it a warning ? ;) As pointed out by Kirit, I would change the order... Go with 2 first, and take help some time from 1 or 3 in parallel..

Comment: Going with Option 1 first would be better as it does not overwhelm you with all the new gems and rspec and all that. Once you understand the Basic flow of a simple Rails application only then go ahead with option 2 which is an awesome step by step guide on how to learn and develop a Rails application.

Comment: that depends in option 2 which book you are referring... Rails guide is a reference book, without completing any tutorial, using reference is not a good idea.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Rails Guide is a complete guide, BUT out of that I wanted newbies to read at least the `Getting Started with Rails` which has excellent basic tutorial to get a jumpstart, I am not saying to read the Entire reference guide BTW thats where everyone goes anyway for reference. If they wish to be master.

Answer (score 0):

In `UserSessionsController` the `new` and `create` methods refer to controller actions that correspond to particular RESTful HTTP requests (routes). In this case, a `GET /user_sessions/new` HTTP request would invoke `UserSessionsController#new` and a `POST /user_sessions` HTTP request would invoke `UserSessionsController#create`.

The `new` action renders the form (found at `views/user_sessions/new.html.erb`) for creating a new user session. That view expects you to provide a user session object as `@user_session`, which is accomplished in the controller's `new` action by the `@user_session = UserSession.new` statement. Without that line, the view is trying to render the form with a `nil` object reference, resulting in your error.

The `create` action handles the form submission that comes from `new`. It expects to see a hash of properties that are appropriate for a `UserSession`. `UserSession.new` is called with that hash of properties, creating a new `UserSession` populated with data from the submitted form. Calling `save` on the `UserSession` instance runs validations, which can potentially fail. You can see that if the save succeeds, the controller will redirect the user to the root URL with a "Success!" flash message. If it fails, it sends the user back to the form to fix their mistakes.

Comment: Chris, Thanks. So as you mentioned "new" action is used to render a form for taking the user input. so is it mandatory that the name of that action has to be always "new"? If not, then how a particular action alone is being identified for this purpose?

Comment: Okay, Now i could make some conclusion correct me if am wrong. The name of the action for this purpose can be anything but what makes difference is we should use the same name while creating and saving the form input. Am i making any sense??

Comment: `new` is one of the default Rails routes. It is defined in your `config/routes.rb` file (line 5 in the example project you linked). Calling `map.resources` (or just `resources` in recent Rails) defines 7 default routes/actions (`index`, `new`, `create`, `show`, `edit`, `update` and `delete`) for a resource. `new` corresponds to a `GET /user_sessions/new` HTTP request. You could map that request to whatever action you like by adding this to `config/routes.rb`: `get '/user_sessions/new', to: 'user_sessions#my_custom_method'`. This is worth reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

The 'new' action is generally used in combination with a user interface that will accept input from the user such as a form.  It is not strictly necessary that the new action create a new UserSession object, but it is necessary if you want to use a "form_for" helper.

```
<% form_for @user_session do |f| %>
```

As you can see, if @article is not defined, this form will raise an error.  The benefits of using form_for are that rails will automatically generated the correct params for you when you submit the form and send the form-data to the create action.  For example:

```
<% form_for @user_session do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :user_session %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :user_session %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

This form will create a param user_session[:user_session] when you submit the form.  Now, when you call:

```
@user_session=UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
```

the @user_session object will have its user_session attribute automatically set to the value passed in by the form.  This might seem trivial when there is only one attribute, but in a form with many attributes the ability to instantiated a new object and set all the attributes in one line is nice.

This functionality can be recreated by hand but the form_for helper does all the work for you.